# Laravel 5.6 Policy is not working properly on remote server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-authorization

I create a policy called `LetterPolicy` , this is the code

```
    namespace App\Policies;

    use App\Letter;
    use App\User;
    use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

    class LetterPolicy
    {
        use HandlesAuthorization;

        /**
         * Create a new policy instance.
         *
         * @return void
         */

        public function __construct()
        {
            //
        }

        public function update(User $user, Letter $letter)
        {
            return($user->id === $letter->user_id || $user->role_id===1 ) ;
        }
    }
```

and this is `authserviceprovider`

```
namespace App\Providers;

use App\Letter;
use App\Policies\LetterPolicy;
use App\Policies\UserPolicy;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
        'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
        User::class => UserPolicy::class,
        Letter::class => LetterPolicy::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();
        //
    }
}
```

And in the following code I check for the user

```
class LetterController extends Controller
{
protected $user;
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next){
       $this->user = Auth::user();
        return $next($request);
    });

}
public function edit(Letter $letter)
{
    if($this->user->can('update', $letter)){           
       //edit
    }
    else
        abort('403', 'Access Denied');
}
```

The code is working well in localhost but on the remote server it reports the `access denied` error. I created this policy after deploying the site on the server so I create a route `/clear-cache` with code

```
    Route::get('/clear-cache', function() {
        $exitCode = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::call('cache:clear');
    });
```

To clear the cache after creating the policy. But it still reports the `403` error. What is the problem?

Comment: Check th permissions of Policy Class file and also try running composer dump-autoload

Comment: @SyedFaisal How can I run composer on server?

Comment: Do you have ssh access to the server??

Comment: yes I have access

Comment: Login to your server using ssh, you can use putty for windows and terminal for linux, navigate to your project directory, will be in /var/www/ or public_html if you are using cpannel, and try to run composer

Comment: @SyedFaisal I manually upload the vendor and composer and composer.lock to server. the error still persists

Comment: Is the user can actually edit the letter? Maybe your data is wrong and policy works correct?

Comment: @OzanKurt yes it can

Comment: @OzanKurt I tried `dd($this->user->id === $letter->user_id || $this->user->role_id===1 );` and it returned `false`. I tried `dd($this->user->id == $letter->user_id || $this->user->role_id==1 );` and it was `true`. Now it works but I don't know why!!!

Comment: @SyedFaisal I tried `dd($this->user->id === $letter->user_id || $this->user->role_id===1 );` and it returned `false`. I tried `dd($this->user->id == $letter->user_id || $this->user->role_id==1 );` and it was `true`. Now it works but I don't know why!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried `dd($this->user->id === $letter->user_id || $this->user->role_id===1 );` in the COntroller and it returned `false`. I tried `dd($this->user->id == $letter->user_id || $this->user->role_id==1 );` and it was `true`. Now it works but I don't know why!!!

Comment: You did `===` instead of `==`. Using `===` will enforce same type comparison and will not do hidden type casting as the `==` does. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-php-equality-double-equals-and-identity-triple-equals-comp) Apparently or `$this->user->id` and `$letter->user_id` are not of the same type or `$this->user->role_id` is not an integer. By using `==` it does not compare types, so then it will return true. Try to `dd()` the variables, then you can see the types in the browser.

Answer (score 2):

Fjarlaegur's answer was the key. I had the same problem: in localhost there was no issue, but in production server somehow every authorization failed and it was because of the comparison operator. Changed from === to == and all as good.